# Group by date through a collection's children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following:

Goals and log entries.

A goal has their own set of log entries.

I'm pulling in 4 goals.

```
@goals = @user.goals.where(name: Goal::DIET_NAMES)
```

Calories, Carbs, Fat, and Proteins.

I'd like to pull all the log entries for each of those goals and then group them by date, so I could display them in a table like this:

[Table of macros](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s66/sh/716378b2-e695-45f4-ac40-f0a0edd4d605/4462c7a81ec98c36bd1bd2e56de360bd/res/6068b4fa-2da5-4455-be70-86001e48308e/skitch.png)

How can I iterate through each goal and then group up all the log entries by date then render that in a view?

---

Right now I can only understand how to iterate through each goals log entries but then I wouldn't be able to display a grouped row for each of the goal types. It would look like a separate table for each goal. Instead I want to create a row for each goal's log entries per date.

edit: Here's a nasty way I am half-way there:

```
  @log_entries = []
  @goals.each do |goal|
    @log_entries << goal.log_entries
  end
  @log_entries.flatten!
```

I'm not sure how to group that by date though? Goal is to group all of the log_entries by date so each one that matches on a date can be a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@goals = @user.goals.where(name: Goal::DIET_NAMES).includes(:log_entries)
# using includes to eager load the log entries (not necessary but optimizes db queries)

@log_entries = @goals.flat_map(&:log_entries).
                      group_by{|x| x.created_at.to_date}
# returns an Array of hashes where
# key is the created date 
# value is an Array of log entries for that date
# E.g. [{created_date1 => [log1,log2..]}, {created_date2 => [log3,..]}..]

# In view 
<%= @log_entries.each do |date, logs| %>
   #here logs is an array of log entries for the date
<% end %>
```